# Adding column to dataframe in pandas by calculating length of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe in which first coloumn is having names. Now I want to add length of that string as a second coloumn in dataframe

```
list = ["apple","mango","banana","orange"]
df=pd.DataFrame(list)
```

is the code for dataframe for example ...
I want dataframe as

```
        0  len
0   apple    5
1   mango    5
2   banana   6
3   ora      3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
import pandas as pd


list = ["apple","mango","banana","orange"]
df=pd.DataFrame(list)

df['len'] = df.iloc[:,0].str.len()
print df
        0  len
0   apple    5
1   mango    5
2  banana    6
3  orange    6
```

Or:

```
list = ["apple","mango","banana","orange"]
df=pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['a'])

df['len'] = df['a'].str.len()
print df
        a  len
0   apple    5
1   mango    5
2  banana    6
3  orange    6
```